# Embedding binary library into Android app

Tags: android, shell, sh

I'm coding apps that use busybox binary library stored in my project's assets folder. In runtime I copy this library to `/data/data/com.myapp/` folder, I make this file executable and than try to execute some util cmds that should be available from this binary lib. But I have not get desired result. I use next function:

```
    private void shellCmd()
    {
        try {
            Process process = null;

            /* I used this to make the file executable */
//          process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/chmod 777 " 
//                                        + this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/busybox");
//          process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ls -l "
//                    + this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/busybox");

            /* this exec function doesnt execute(there is no prompt into logcat)*/
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/busybox ping -4 46.173.103.134");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read); 
            }
            reader.close();
            Log.w("groupAB",output.toString());
            Log.i("groupAB", "finish");
            process.waitFor();

            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

But when I'm trying to execute the same cmd using adb in way `"adb shell /data/data/com.myapp/busybox ping -4 46.173.103.134"` I get corect ping result. I'm confused why this doesn't work in a programming way. Where is my fault?

Comment: Does your app have the INTERNET permission declared in its manifest?

Comment: @fadden sure, it does

Comment: I have checked your codes: /system/bin/chmod 777 "                                        + this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/busybox" . And does your device own the root right? Or your device has been rooted.